# Combining multiple columns to 1 in angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I was trying the example of material 2 table as explained in this [tutorial](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)and it worked nice.

My problem is that in their api or example they have nowhere mention of to combine 2 separate columns to one single column.

I have having this data..

1. Column 1 - User ID
2. Columns 2 - First name
3. Columns 3 - Last name
4. Column 4 - Address

I want to a new columns which will replace Column2 and Column3 (i.e want to make new column with name `Full Name` which will be Coulmn2 + column3 )

Is there any way so that i can achieve the desired functionality.
I dont want to edit the data at server side for this. this should be only done via frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, map your server data into the object format you want to use:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  address: string;
}

interface UserDisplay {
  id: string;
  fullName: string;
  address: string;
}

const displayUsers: UserDisplay[] = this.getAllUsers()
  .map(user => {
    return {
      id: user.id,
      fullName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
      address: user.address,
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate values of several columns inside the moustache binding:

```
<md-cell *mdCellDef="let row"> {{row.id.toString() + ' ' + row.name.toString()}} </md-cell>
```

See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/X22fU4wStb9yGLwZXGYJ?p=preview).